# Split string in PLSQL

Tags: plsql

Following should return Y

```
CASISA#Y

INVOPT#LUMREG#LUMSUM#2000#REGSUM#8000

LUMSUM#2000#REGSUM#8000
```

i.e Hash separates Code and Value and it also separates Code, Value pairs (earlier semicolon used to separate Code, Value pairs)

Following should return N (as these are incorrect input string formats)

```
CASISA#

INVOPT#LUMREG#LUMSUM

LUMSUM#2000#REGSUM#8000#
```

Answer (score 1):

`case when regexp_like(your_string||'#', '^(\w+#\w+#)+$') then 'Y' else 'N' end`

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df293/4)